# FutureBuilder contains previous search result element

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

For some weird reason, after searching for the second time, given I already have a list with the first search results, when I click on an element it displays information from the first search result.
I don't understand why.

```
return Expanded(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: showSearchObject,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<AllTVShowList> snapshot) {
            if ( !snapshot.hasData){
              ...
            }
            else{
              ....
              return Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                          height: _height,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.showList.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                              print(snapshot.data.showList[index].name);
                              return ShowCard(show: snapshot.data.showList[index]);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                    ),
                  ],
              );
            }
          }
      ),
  );
```

Comment: Every time you execute a search you should set the state of the widget so that FutureBuilder can be reset using the new search query.

Comment: I also noticed it's only happening to the list elements which are visible, when I scroll I can see they are getting updated, but the first 3 which are visible got the content from the previous search.

Comment: Like their init it's not calling after they are buing built

Comment: Hmm, can you post your `showSearchObject` function?

Comment: Future<AllTVShowList> showSearchObject; -declaration

Comment: _searchShows(String text) {
    setState(() {
      _showName = text;
      _searched = true;
      showSearchObject = getSearchResults(showName: _showName);
    });
  }
//On submitting the textfield calling the function.
onSubmitted: (value) {
              _searchShows(value);
              _icon = Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white,);
            },

Comment: `onSubmitted: (value) {
              _searchShows(value);
              _icon = Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white,);
            },`